# Wordpress: front-end edit a custom post type with only password login

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

This could be a tricky — I hope someone can help!

Context: I have a custom application in Wordpress that is based on registered and unregistered users posting custom post types from the front end.

Problem: Obviously the users that are registered will only need to sign in to edit their posts, but what I need to do is allow unregistered users to set a post password when creating the post and present them with only a password field when they would like to edit their post. Essentially they would enter the password they set (and a hidden field would reference the referring post ID) and it would log them in and present them with the edit screen—the same as a registered user would see if they logged in and edited their posts. I understand the security risks here.

Hope someone can help! Thanks!

Comment: Whats the point of allowing unregistered users to set a password to a post, why not have them all register? Are you assuming that unregistered users will come back to your app/site to edit their posts? What if the unregistered user has multiple posts, he or she has to then remember each of the posts they made?  Just curious :)

Comment: Think classified ad website powered by Wordpress - will need to support those who do not wish to sign up for an account! ;)

Comment: You could use `post meta` to store salted and md5 passwords attached to the post id. Such as the unregistered user creates a post with an ID (obvious part) and then has password field which is connected to your wordpress via `post meta`, then you get post only if their password matches retrieved the data.. makes sense? otherwise create a custom database table that works with (joined) the `post_id` to store unregistered user passwords and same way of retrieval...